# Need help on Django Modelling

Tags: python, django, models, modeling

I am creating a Django app and this questions comes to hit me again (I've already run into it but I resolved it in a way I don't think is correct).

So I have these models:

```
def Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    status = models.ManyToManyField(Status)

def Status(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

Any person may have up to 3 status (or none). And this was supposed to be a string array containing only a few possible status. e.g. happy, lucky, strong.

However a CharField with choices would not be possible here, as one person may feel happy and strong at the same time.

Is my current approach the best one possible?

Comment: You could possibly have multiple boolean attributes under status (One for each mood)?

Comment: If you want to have only  few possible statuses, consider a [fixture](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/initial-data/)?

Comment: Yes, I will have a fixture for Status.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to validate the statuses count for each person in the `clean` method.

```
from django.db import models
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError


class Status(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)


class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    status = models.ManyToManyField(Status)

    def clean(self):
        # check person status count
        if self.status.all().count() > 3:
            raise ValidationError("Person can not have more than 3 statuses")
```

---

**Update**

Since it's a `ManyToMany` relationship, you will never get this validated during the creation of the object, *unless you have a separate form for adding statuses for persons*.

If you have statuses field in the same form of person creation, then this check MUST be in the form.

```
class PersonForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Person

    def clean(self):
        statuses = self.cleaned_data.get('status')
        if status.count() > 3:
            raise ValidationError("Person can not have more than 3 statuses")
```

---

**Why this method**

This design of models will allow you to have many different ways of querying. such as `get people who are happy!` or `count of people who are sad` and finally get people with similar statuses

Comment: Ok, but do you think this is the best method? Creating a model for Status is strange for me because it only has one field. But I guess it's the only way, right?

Comment: @agnans What's your requirements? If you want person to have many statuses and status can have many people then you are in the right track.

Answer (score 0):

Just a quick addition - if you're using PostgreSQL (and that's probably the best decision) you could also use an Array Field, for which you can specify a max size.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use a tagging library like [Django-taggit](https://readthedocs.org/projects/django-taggit/)